# How do I stop the Google Drive Picker UI to close automatically after choosing particular file?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, picker, google-picker

By default, Google Picker closes automatically if I select any file (csv or text or xls). I want that it should close only if the extension is csv format.

Please suggest what change do I need to do here in my code.

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    var file_Id = '';
    var fileType = '';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        console.log(doc);
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        file_Id = doc.id;
        fileType = doc.mimeType;
        if (fileType != "text/csv") {
            alert("Error: Selected item is not CSV file");
            // Google Picker closes automatically - Problem
            // Restrict Google Picker from closing here
        } else {
            // Google Picker closes automatically - OK
            downloadfile(file_Id); // function to perform on fetched file
        }
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url + ' having File Id: ' + file_Id;
    console.log(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Picker API has a method for specifying selectable MIME types.

> #### PickerBuilder.setSelectableMimeTypes(string)
>
> Set the list of MIME types which will be selectable. Use commas to separate MIME types if more than one is required.

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#PickerBuilder

## Example

```
const view = new window.google.picker.DocsView();
const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  .addView(view)
  .setSelectableMimeTypes('text/csv')
  .setCallback(pickerCallback)
  .build();
```

---

Optionally you can restrict which MIME types that should be displayed so the user will only see `text/csv` files.

> #### View.setMimeTypes(string)
>
> For views listing documents, set the MIME types which will be included in the view. Use commas to separate MIME types if more than one is required.

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#View

## Example

```
const view = new window.google.picker.DocsView().setMimeTypes('text/csv');
const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  .addView(view)
  .setCallback(pickerCallback)
  .build();
```